# error in sas macro - A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required

Tags: if-statement, sas, macros

this is my code:

```
data a ;
     y = month(date()) ;
     CALL SYMPUT ('y', y) 
     ;
run ;

OPTIONS MINOPERATOR ;
%MACRO TEST;
        %IF &y. NOT IN (1,4,7,10)
        %THEN %DO ;
            PROC SQL ;
            SELECT INPUT(Legacy_Bnk_Order_Ctrl_Id,4.) INTO: parameter_acc separated by ',' 
            FROM WORK.parameter_acc_table 
            ;
            RUN ;
        %END ;
        %ELSE %DO ;
        %LET parameter_acc = '0' ;
        %PUT &parameter_acc. ;
        %END ;
%MEND TEST;

%TEST;
```

I am getting the following LOG info and ERROR:

SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Y resolves to            9
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was:
&y. NOT IN (1,4,7,10)
ERROR: The macro TEST will stop executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just insert the keyword NOT into the middle of an expression using the IN operator.  Instead use it to negate the result of the IN operator.

```
%if NOT &y in (A,B) ...
```

Here is cleaned up code:

```
data a ;
  y = month(date()) ;
  CALL SYMPUTX('y', y);
run ;

%MACRO TEST / minoperator mindelimiter=',';
%IF not &y. IN (1,4,7,10) %THEN %DO ;
PROC SQL noprint;
  SELECT INPUT(Legacy_Bnk_Order_Ctrl_Id,4.) 
    INTO :parameter_acc separated by ',' 
  FROM WORK.parameter_acc_table 
;
quit;
%END ;
%ELSE %DO ;
  %LET parameter_acc = 0 ;
%END ;
%PUT &parameter_acc. ;
%MEND TEST;

%let parameter_acc = BEFORE MACRO CALL;
%TEST;
```

Comment: I found that it is better to ise Ne instead. Tanks

Comment: But the operator NE (not equal) does not work with multiple values like the IN operator does.  You can only use it to test one value at a time.